# How to change the counting style of my float caption

Tags: floats, captions, memoir, counters

I'm trying to change the counting style of my float captions so that it uses only one counting (1, 2, 3, ...) without the chapter number included. my document class is "memoir". my main.tex file looks like this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,natbib,square,oneside]{memoir} 
\newsubfloat{figure}
\newsubfloat{table}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{point}{. }
\captionsetup{labelsep=point, labelfont=bf, textfont=normalfont, font=small}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
```

Nothing changes and I still get the number of chapter before the number of figure or table even with the last two commands. 
When using a figure or table, I put the above code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textheight]{fig01/processus}
    \caption{Les étapes de prévision d'une maladie agricole.}
    \label{fig:processus}
\end{figure}
```

[image: This is what i've got]

Am I missing something here ? Help needed please!

Comment: Does \newsubfloat serve any purpose here?

Comment: No it dosn't but it's part of the code I'm using to include subfigures and subtables in a memoir class document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}`, which will give the desired result.

[image: numbering]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,natbib,square,oneside]{memoir} 
\newsubfloat{figure}
\newsubfloat{table}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{point}{. }
\captionsetup{labelsep=point, labelfont=bf, textfont=normalfont, font=small}

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textheight]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Les étapes de prévision d'une maladie agricole.}
    \label{fig:processus}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually your code works well in a simple tex file, but not when using the commands \frontmatter, \mainmatter & \backmatter to separate the file parts. To solve my problem I only needed  to remove these 3 commands and set the numbering style of my pages manually .

Comment: @SarraRoza That may be right, but I just answered your question regarding your fragments of code. If you added some more details/code the answer may have differed. You have to decide whether to accept this answer for the described problem or not.

Comment: your answer is accepted because it does the job, sorry  I just didn't know which fragments of code I must include in my question.

Comment: @SarraRoza Thank you. It is in general (just as recommendation) a good idea to include a code which is compilable (so just copy, paste and compile shows the problem).

Comment: If \counterwithout functions like \@addtoreset, you should be able to add it at the start of \mainmatter.  I'm not sure what to do with \backmatter other than change \thefigure.